# Bootstrap & Wordpress issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

it will probably something stupid as ussual but.. I can't get my style.css or custom.css to override the bootstrap css. I don't wanna put all my custom css in my header file because that is not really the way to do it I suppose..

Now I Tried to add it in my functions.php like this:

```
    //Enqueue scripts and styles
function horizon_scripts() {
    //Load the theme CSS

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/custom.css', array(), '1.0.1', 'all' );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'horizon_scripts' );
```

So it loads my bootstrap css first and then the style.css and custom.css but that didn't quite hit it..

So any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Just tried it, but still not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri). Here's just the css, without your js:

```
function horizon_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('bootstrap') );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.css', array('main') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'horizon_scripts' );
```

Note that the third parameter of `wp_enqueue_style()` is "dependencies". Read more [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Comment: Thank you so much, finally got it working. Google did not help me this time but you did :D